# Can images be block-hilighted? (like text)

Tags: image, ckeditor, selection, contenteditable

I'm trying to adapt ckeditor, where the content is not text, but images only, where each image displays a character in the alphabet. (By creating an image from an off-screen canvas object)

Only problem is that users can't do block selections by dragging over them (like you would with text).  Is this even possible in the contentEditble world? I was hoping that setting the draggable attribute to false for each  tag would do it - but no dice :-(

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes:
I've copied the image in the demo and then I'm able to drag select all of them.
I guess that it might be harder to control the selection like you do with text.

[image]

Comment: Ah, but I think you cheated! :-)  I think you took advantage of the text that's still in there.  Try this: remove all the text, use 4 images, and try to drag-select images 2 thru 3

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work now. Just had to listen for mouse & key events and handle the selection manually.